# How to query a condition on a single object of sql record?

Tags: mariadb

I'll try my best to explain the situation here. We are using MariaDB.

In certain case we are looping over all the records/rows of a REQUESTS table.
and for each object/record we are checking few conditions and if condition passes we are performing an action. All the said things here are being done using ruby. Say I want to check the same on pure SQL, I wanted to see how.

Sample Object a Request table:

```
[{"ot_rqst_id":27460354,"rqst_type_cd":"NONTP","svc_type_cd":"TD","sl_ttl_type_cd":"","lot_num":41843022, ttl_stg_cd: 'CMPLT'}]
```

**What I want to check on sql:**
To see **if** the **ttl_stg_cd** of this object is equal to '**CMPLT**'. **If** it is **then** **update** it to NULL else "something_else".

Let me remind you again that, I am already doing this in ruby language, but I am not an expert on sql so help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For all rows in the table it would be an [update](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/update/), like the following:

```
   UPDATE Requests
   SET ttl_stg_cd = IF(ttl_stg_cd = CMPLT, NULL, "something else")
```

Assuming your notation is referring to a table with rows and not just a json blob in a row.